# USB debugging doesn’t work with physical device/cmdline-tools component is missing/flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, android-sdk-manager, flutter-doctor

I created an app and my problem is that I can’t debug via USB cable because it doesn’t recognize my Smartphone.

If I run flutter doctor it shows me this error:

```
Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version
    32.1.0-rc1)
    X cmdline-tools component is missing
      Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more
      details.
    X Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See
      https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup
```

If I run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"` it doesn’t do anything.

Does anyone have a solution for my problem?

Comment: Did you already have sdkmanager installed ?

Comment: Have you replaced `path/to/sdkmanager` with the real path before runnning the command? Do you where it is installed on your system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. For the First Problem, Open Android Studio and Go to `SDK Manager > SDK Tools` there you will find `Android SDK Command-line Tools` check the checkbox and press Apply button to install it.

[image]

2. For the second problem just enter the command `flutter doctor --android-licenses` on Terminal/Command Prompt and accept all the licenses.