# Android Studio - I imported a file from GitHub but when I run it it gives an error

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, github

I'm working on a Flutter app that I imported from GitHub
But when I run it it does not work and gives this error
and when I create a new app it doesn't show any problems

[image][image]

Comment: Have you tried to run flutter doctor on terminal/command prompt?

Comment: it gives this problem:

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
    X cmdline-tools component is missing
      Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.
    X Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details.

Comment: Use this (https://stackoverflow.com/a/71527159/13378076) to fix the problem raised by flutter doctor.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio Error "Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66980512/android-studio-error-android-gradle-plugin-requires-java-11-to-run-you-are-cur)

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to create a new project and replace the main files (lib folder files and configuration files.
However, you mentioned that you cloned the project from github and there is a big chance that many libraries are not included because it is not meant to be tracked by git. If this is the case try the solution by @JDawg

[Visual Studio Code - Target of URI doesn't exist 'package:flutter/material.dart'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44909653/visual-studio-code-target-of-uri-doesnt-exist-packageflutter-material-dart)

Answer (score 0):

Open your Project's `android` folder in Android Studio and from Menu go to `Android Studio > Preferences > Build,Execution,Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle`. Now here change `Gradle JDK` version from 1.8 to 11 (given in dropdown).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new flutter project in studio and then replace your `lib` folder and dependencies in `pubspec.yaml` if there are some. This could defend you from unexpected errors while working with old projects.